# Type inference and inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, type-inference

I have a base class that has some functionality that uses type inference...

```
public abstract class Processor<T>
{
    ...
    public IProcessBuilder<T, TResult> Process<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> propertyOfT)
    {
    }

    public abstract void SetProcessors();
}
```

Then I have two classes:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EntityChild : EntityBase
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And over these two I also have two processors that configure these two classes:

```
public class EntityBaseProcessor : Processor<EntityBase>
{
    public override void SetProcessors()
    {
        base.SetProcessors();
        this.Process(entity => entity.Name)
            .DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that I would like to reuse configured process of base entity class for the child class as well to avoid code duplication:

```
public class EntityChildProcessor: EntityBaseProcessor
{
    public override void SetProcessors()
    {
        base.SetProcessor();
        this.Process(entity => /* entity.Description is of course missing */)
            .DoSomething();
    }
}
```

### Question

I'm apparently tired because I can't seem to find a feasible way to reuse processor classes because inherited processor class should also use the inherited entity class for processing.

I can of course repeat the code and write my other processor as:

```
public class EntityChildProcessor: Processor<EntityChild>
{
    public override void SetProcessors()
    {
        base.SetProcessor();
        // repeated code for inherited property
        this.Process(entity => entity.Name)
            .DoSomething();
        this.Process(entity => entity.Description)
            .DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would it be reasonable to you to declare `EntityBaseProcessor` as a generic class? Something like this:

```
public class EntityBaseProcessor<TEntityBase> : Processor<TEntityBase>
    where TEntityBase : EntityBase
{
    public override void SetProcessors()
    {
        base.SetProcessors();
        this.Process(entity => entity.Name)
            .DoSomething();
    }
}

public class EntityChildProcessor : EntityBaseProcessor<EntityChild>
{
    public override void SetProcessors()
    {
        base.SetProcessors();
        this.Process(entity => entity.Description)
            .DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make EntityBaseProcessor generic as well:

```
public class EntityBaseProcessor<T> : Processor<T> where T : EntityBase

public class EntityChildProcessor<T> : EntityBaseProcessor<T> where T : EntityChild
```

Or: (you can trade the simplicity of a non-generic `EntityChildProcessor` for the downside of permanently setting `T`'s type)

```
public sealed class EntityChildProcessor : EntityBaseProcessor<EntityChild>
```

Comment: +1: your answer also helped my solution, but I accepted the other answer for more complete code. Still awarded you points for valid answer.